# Como abrir solo un acordeón a la vez con Angular 11 y Nebular

Tags: angular11

Verán estoy intentando de que al presionar un acordeón y luego al presionar otro se cierre automáticamente el anterior, creo que tendría que validarlo contra el index de cada acordeón, pero no se como hacer eso, alguien me podría ayudar con eso?

O si hay alguna manera de crear una variable que pueda manejar el estado?

Saludos.

**Codigo HTMl**

```
      <nb-accordion style="width: 500px;" (click)="getListaMateriales(item.ItemCode)">
        <nb-accordion-item>
          <nb-accordion-item-header>
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
              <h4 class="mb-0 text-center text-hint" style="width: 2rem;">{{letra(i)}}</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="flex-grow-1" style="min-height: 45px;">
              <div class="d-block">
                <label class="font-weight-bold mb-0">{{item.ItemName}}</label>
              </div>
              <span class="text-hint text-sm">{{item.ItemCode}}</span>

              <div class="form-row">
                <ng-container *ngFor="let mat of item.listaMateriales">
                  <ng-container *ngIf="mat.activo == false">
                    <div class="col-6 pr-2 text-sm">
                      <i class="fas fa-minus-square text-danger"></i>
                      SIN {{mat.ItemName}}
                    </div>
                  </ng-container>
                </ng-container>
              </div>
            </div>

              <div class="d-flex align-items-center mx-2">
                <div>
                  <h5 class="mb-0 text-center text-info" *ngIf="item.articuloBaseMenuCod != null">
                    {{(item.detalleOportunidad.Quantity * item.articuloBaseMenu.baseMenu.cantidad)}}
                  </h5>
                  <h5 class="mb-0 text-center text-info" *ngIf="item.articuloBaseMenuCod == null">
                    {{item.detalleOportunidad.Quantity}}
                  </h5>
                  <span class="text-hint text-sm">Cantidad</span>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="d-flex align-items-center mr-3 px-2">
                <button type="button" nbButton status="primary" (click)="setPreparado(item.codArticuloDetalleOportunidad)" [disabled]="item.estadoProduccion">
                  <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
                </button>
              </div>
          </nb-accordion-item-header>

            <nb-accordion-item-body>
              <ul>
                <li *ngFor="let item of materialArticulo">
                  {{item.ItemName}}
                </li>
              </ul>
            </nb-accordion-item-body>
        </nb-accordion-item>
      </nb-accordion>
```

**Codigo de TS**

```
  getListaMateriales(cod: string): void {
    this.listadoMaterialesSvc.getList(cod).subscribe(res => {
      this.materialArticulo = res;
    }, error => {
      this.toastr.error(error);
    });
  }
```

Espero alguien pueda ayudarme!!
Saludos y gracias de antemano por su tiempo.

Comment: En la documentación está un ejemplo que funciona así.

Comment: @Lobos Lo he intentado, pero mi caso es diferente al de la documentación

Comment: pero en el código que nostras para la estructura de Nebular hay solo una <nb-accordion></nb-accordion> que contiene a un solo <nb-accordion-item></nb-accordion-item>
Entonces a que te referís al decir al presionar un acordeón y luego al presionar otro se cierre automáticamente el anterior? para que sean dos hay que defnir dos <nb-accordion></nb-accordion> que contengan cada uno un  <nb-accordion-item> al menos asi esta el la pagina para la estructura a respetar

Comment: @nestdan Lo siento! Me falto el nb-card que envuelve a todo el acordeón, básicamente lo que estoy haciendo es iterar un array, por  lo que habrá un acordeón por cada item. Pero ya lo solucione gracias!! En un momento posteo la respuesta